# Parse Rows Into 2 Columns Licence# and Item #

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parsing, sql-server-2017

I have some data in the database that is stored comma separated. I need to parse it so that I have one too many. The data looks like the following. From the query I've created, I have gotten this far but become stuck as I go back and forth and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Results:

[image]

Expected

[image]

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testdata;
    CREATE TABLE testdata (
        LicenseNumberList VARCHAR(100),
        ItemNumberList VARCHAR(100)
    );

    -- Insert data
    INSERT INTO testdata (LicenseNumberList, ItemNumberList)
    VALUES ('[1234],[8854],[6987]', '[4555,8777,4444],[4415],[4444]');

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.SplitString
GO
-- Create a split function
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitString
(
    @String VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE (Value VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(MAX)
    
    WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Value = SUBSTRING(@String, 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String) - 1)
        INSERT INTO @Result (Value) VALUES (@Value)
        SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String) + 1, LEN(@String))
    END
    
    IF LEN(@String) > 0
        INSERT INTO @Result (Value) VALUES (@String)
    
    RETURN
END;
GO

-- Split the license numbers and item numbers into separate rows
WITH LicenseNumbersParsed AS (
    SELECT
        LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(Value, '[', ''), ']', ''))) AS LicenseNumber,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber
    FROM
        testdata
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitString(LicenseNumberList, ',')
), ItemNumbersParsed AS (
    SELECT
        ln.RowNumber,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(Value, '[', ''), ']', ''))) AS ItemNumber,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ln.RowNumber ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ItemRowNumber
    FROM
        testdata
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitString(ItemNumberList, ',')
    JOIN LicenseNumbersParsed ln ON 1 = 1
)
SELECT
    ln.LicenseNumber,
    STRING_AGG(ip.ItemNumber, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ip.ItemRowNumber) AS ItemNumberList
FROM
    LicenseNumbersParsed ln
JOIN ItemNumbersParsed ip ON ln.RowNumber = ip.RowNumber
GROUP BY
    ln.LicenseNumber
ORDER BY
    ln.LicenseNumber;
```

Comment: Why are you not using `STRING_SPLIT`? That is a terribly unperformant function you have there. It's an mlTVF, which are known to perform poorly, and it uses a `WHILE`, which are known to perform poorly. Add 2 features that perform poorly and you get a *very* poorly performing query.

Comment:  Please never use [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data. Your function does not appear to return any ordinal position so why are you not using [String_Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Though what you should really do is fix your design; *never* store delimited data in your database

Comment: @ThomA I modified my SQL to include that instead. Most of this code is pre-me; I am just trying to get it to work correctly. I didn't change the function as it was using it.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution. It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

It is based on the @lptr idea.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (LicenseNumberList VARCHAR(100), ItemNumberList VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (LicenseNumberList, ItemNumberList)
VALUES ('[1234],[8854],[6987]', '[4555,8777,4444],[4415],[4444]');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT LicenseNumber = JSON_VALUE(l.value, '$[0]')
    , ItemNumber = TRIM('[]' FROM JSON_QUERY('['+t.ItemNumberList+']', '$['+l.[key] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT +']'))
FROM @tbl AS t 
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('['+t.LicenseNumberList+']') AS l;
```

**Output**

| LicenseNumber | ItemNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 4555,8777,4444 |
| 8854 | 4415 |
| 6987 | 4444 |

Answer (score 0):

You can join using the new `ordinal` column of `STRING_SPLIT` in SQL Server 2022 and SQL Azure.

You also need to handle the embedded `,` within the `[]`, you can do this by replacing the outer `],[` with `|`

```sql
SELECT
  LicenseNumberList = TRIM('[] ' FROM lnl.value),
  ItemNumberList    = TRIM('[] ' FROM inl.value)
FROM testdata td
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(td.LicenseNumberList, '],[', '|'), '|', 1) lnl
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(td.ItemNumberList,    '],[', '|'), '|', 1) inl
WHERE lnl.ordinal = inl.ordinal;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/TKa5t_Jt)

Comment: will not work with 2017

Answer (score 0):

I use Your Function and Cte  ,First use REPLACE '],[' with '_' and Remove ']' ,'['

Then use cross apply to Create Whole List and find Correct Result

```
with _list as (
        select 
                REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE(LicenseNumberList, '],[', '_'),'[',''),']','') as LicenseNumberList
                ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ItemNumberList, '],[', '_'),'[',''),']','') as ItemNumberList
        from testdata a
)
select 
               vLicenseNumberList.Value as LicenseNumberList
              ,vItemNumberList.Value as ItemNumberList
from (
        select *
        from _list a
        cross apply(select *,row_number() over(order by  LicenseNumberList)  as ID 
        from SplitString(LicenseNumberList,'_'))vLicenseNumberList

)vLicenseNumberList
cross apply(select *,row_number() over(order by ItemNumberList)   as ID 
from SplitString(ItemNumberList,'_'))vItemNumberList
where vLicenseNumberList.ID=vItemNumberList.ID
```